mat.button-color not working for mat-raised button
I have created a custom-theme, and using it in my styles.scss like this:
.alternate-theme-green {
  @include mat.button-color(m3-green-theme.$light-theme, $color-variant: primary);    
}

this is working fine for mat-flat-button, but when applying same class on mat-raised-button its not working.
Please help.

issue not reproducible stackblitz Demo

@NarenMurali, thanks  a lot,  but I want , raised-button, to have same look as Flat-button, but in raised-button, background-color should be the primary color, not white.

Since you want to transform one button to another, you have to use CSS with variables to define the overrides for this specific type of button.
.alternate-theme-green {
  @include mat.button-color($theme, $color-variant: primary);
}
.alternate-theme-green[mat-raised-button]:not(:disabled) {
  color: var(--mdc-filled-button-label-text-color) !important;
  background-color: var(--mdc-filled-button-container-color) !important;
}

Stackblitz Demo

Yes sir, this is working.

Also, is it possible to control border-radius for buttons?

@raju just add border-radius: 16px !important; to the extra CSS mentioned

Try this in your styles.scss file.


.custom-raised-button {
    background-color: #3f51b5 !important;
    color: white !important; 
    border-radius: 6px !important;
  }
  
  .mat-raised-button.custom-raised-button {
    background-color: #3f51b5 !important; 
    color: white !important;
  }




You can try like this:
.mat-raised-button.alternate-theme-green {
  @include mat.button-color(m3-green-theme.$light-theme, $color-variant: primary);
}


Actually it is doing reverse. In case of Raised button, Background color becomes WHITE, but color (font) is taking from theme. While in case of flat button it is reverse and correct.
